# Prevent re-submitting a form

Tags: html, forms

This might not be a great question to ask. However, when you have a form and after a thank you page appears after the form. If someone press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on chrome, it resubmits the data. Is there any way to stop resubmitting data in the browsers? Basically Instead i want it to reload the form and make the user fill it in again. Is there a way to stop explicitly say to browser that after this point stop caching?

Comment: That's not possible. Refreshing is browser behavior, it's outside of the control of your site.

Comment: @Kenneth not 100% true..

Comment: I am not using PHP. I am using basic java, Struts, html/css

Comment: @user3218006 HTTP is not PHP specific

Comment: oh ok didnt realize the question has answers that are general.. cause the question itself seems like for PHP specific.. looking at it.. though still a little confused

Comment: @user3218006 exactly, it's not about PHP, it's mainly about HTTP headers/status codes sent in the right order. The browser remembers the last HTTP interactoin and if it contained form data, it will pop up if you'd like to resend..

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with caching, although the browser does temporarily store the form data when you refresh or hit the back button. This is browser specific, which is out of your control, however, this behaviour can be circumvented:

1. by submitting the form data via ajax
2. by forcing a non-POST request after the form data POST request